# What encoding should I use in Visual Studio for Romanian?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a c++ console project in Visual Studio 2015 and I need to use Romanian diacritics. No encoding that is available to select from Visual Studio interface works(File-Advanced Save Options - Encoding). All of them give me an error except for UTF-8 with signature, but the diacritics are still not displayed correctly in the console.

Comment: What code are you using to output? If you are using `cout` you should change to `wcout`

Comment: It worked! Thanks!